# React native: importing Images not working

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

I have trouble importing image to my component. I saved the images in a filed called `WidgetImages` and in `Images.js` I wrote this code to import it:

```
var Images = {
    Weather: require('./WidgetsImages/Weather.png'),
    News: require('./WidgetsImages/News.png'),
    AgendaWidget: require('./WidgetsImages/AgendaWidget.png'),
    SpotifyPlayer: require('./WidgetsImages/SpotifyPlayer.png'),
    VoiceReader: require('./WidgetsImages/VoiceReader.png'),
    Clock: require('./WidgetsImages/Clock.png'),
};

export default Images;
```

Then in my component file I have the following:

```
import Images from '../assets/Images';
// code here ... 
<Image source={Images.item} />
```

I can't figure where the problem is. I looked at previous questions and I have the same structure and my imports are correct. So what seems to be the problem here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please past the errors you are getting?
By the code you've pasted, The `<Image source={Images.item} />` line must be as below

```js
<Image source={Images.Weather} />
// item should me replaced by the actual properties of the Images object
```